# Having trouble running mean.io

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mean.io

My app is stuck at `GET / - - - - ms` but the connection's accepted already at mongo.

When i run this is the last before the "get". On the browser it just forever loads. My firewall is also turned off

```
Debugger listening on port 5858
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 0
[20:59:07] index.html reloaded.
```

There's this error when i try to npm install. I think its because of this.

```
meanio-admin@0.1.6 postinstall D:\Projects\mean\node_modules\meanio-admin
> bower install

accepts@1.3.3 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\errorhandler\node_modules\accepts -> node_modules\accepts
charenc@0.0.1 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\md5\node_modules\charenc -> node_modules\charenc
crypt@0.0.1 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\md5\node_modules\crypt -> node_modules\crypt
escape-html@1.0.3 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\errorhandler\node_modules\escape-html -> node_modules\escape-html
express-unless@0.3.0 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\express-jwt\node_modules\express-unless -> node_modules\express-unless
is-buffer@1.1.3 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\md5\node_modules\is-buffer -> node_modules\is-buffer
jws@3.1.3 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\jws -> node_modules\jws
lodash.set@4.2.0 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\express-jwt\node_modules\lodash.set -> node_modules\lodash.set
xtend@4.0.1 node_modules\meanio\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\node_modules\xtend -> node_modules\xtend
mean@0.6.1 D:\Projects\mean
├─┬ meanio-admin@0.1.6  invalid (git://github.com/linnovate/meanio-admin.git#66b03424a94cf51199ba21b5f2ac1d9eefa9e0aa)
│ ├── meanio-circles@0.1.1  (git://github.com/linnovate/meanio-circles.git#42261511e0459364b34f2dfdc0bb0bf8f03794a7)
│ └─┬ meanio-users@0.1.4  (git://github.com/linnovate/meanio-users.git#79dacf5194d2cfa1676ac5ac59066138db37f74d)
│   └── angular-jwt@0.0.9
└── meanio-system@0.1.3  invalid (git://github.com/linnovate/meanio-system.git#a1b1b2b35eec858493d3a308e56d1e2014627ed5)

    Dependencies installed for package meanStarter

> mean@0.6.1 prepublish D:\Projects\mean
> npm run snyk-protect


> mean@0.6.1 snyk-protect D:\Projects\mean
> snyk protect

The patch against "node_modules\npm\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch" (npm:minimatch:20160620) failed.
Email support@snyk.io if this problem persists.
The patch against "node_modules\npm\node_modules\init-package-json\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch" (npm:minimatch:20160620) failed.
Email support@snyk.io if this problem persists.
The patch against "node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch" (npm:minimatch:20160620) failed.
Email support@snyk.io if this problem persists.
The patch against "node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream-npm\node_modules\fstream-ignore\node_modules\minimatch" (npm:minimatch:20160620) failed.
Email support@snyk.io if this problem persists.
Successfully applied Snyk patches
meanio-circles@0.1.1 node_modules\meanio-circles

meanio-system@0.1.3 node_modules\meanio-system

meanio-users@0.1.4 node_modules\meanio-users

meanio-admin@0.1.2 node_modules\meanio-admin
```

How do you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `"snyk": true` to `"snyk": false` in package.json

I've been having problems with the shrinkwrap provided so I blasted everything and reinstalled `npm cache clean && rm -rf node_modules && rm -f npm-shrinkwrap.json`

`npm i && npm shrinkwrap`